# KeyguardManager - requestDismissKeyguard() method alternative for api 25 and below [Android]

Tags: android, keyguard, keyguardlock

I was recently trying to request user to dismiss key-guard manually from my app. My app invokes a activity screen when device is locked and the screen has the flags

FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON

When I have to invoke another screen which does not have these flags I want to request the user to unlock the key-guard, this behaviour can be seen in the the camera app - when we want to share a photo taken while phone is locked it will request us to unlock the device.

[requestDismissKeyguard()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#requestDismissKeyguard(android.app.Activity,%20android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback)) method works only for api26 and above any alternatives for the lower apis ??

Comment: Please add comments if you guys are downvoting

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the downvotes here, have a +1, friend.

Answer (score 2):

you can use flags for lower versions

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
  val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
  keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
} else {
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
}
```

Check for more examples [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/how-to-make-your-android-app-re-appear-without-a-lock-screen-64e897680afe).

Answer (score -3):

you can use createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent in API level 21

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

sample:

```
//region [in some funtion]
if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked()) {
   Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("My Title", "A Custom Description");
   if (intent != null) {
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS);
   }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Secure lock screen hasn't set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
//endregion

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CONFIRM_DEVICE_CREDENTIALS) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent is just used to check if user is known with credentials or not, If password is correct it never UN-LOCKS THE PHONE